# Check engine light with code P0455 comes on when fuel tank is below 3/4 full

Tags: mazda, dtc, evap, miata, p0455

In my 2001 Mazda Miata, the `check engine light` comes on when the fuel tank is at the 3/4 full mark. The code is DTC `P0455 - Evap System Large Leak Detected`

I have replaced the fuel cap already.

1. What could be causing this?
2. How do I diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

Leaks in the evaporative system can be challenging to find. A "large leak" can be a hole as small as .040" in diameter.

Common leaks on this model are:

- Fuel Filler Cap
- Canister Drain Cut Valve (CDCV) also called the Canister Vent Valve
- Purge Solenoid/Valve
- Pressure sensor

Testing is most commonly done by filling the system with smoke from a smoke generator machine and then inspecting the system looking for smoke. The canister valve must be closed first since it is normally open.

The reason the code sets at about 3/4 tank level is that the on-board test is prohibited from running when the fuel level is below 15% and above 85%.